# GWT display HTML of another page inside div

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT.  I have a string which consists of all the HTML for an HTML email, which has some css styles for that email, such as links as green.

I want to display that email inside my GWT app, but when I use the HTML widget and add the HTML I end up changing the CSS styles of the whole page, for example all my links change color to what is specfied in the email.

It seems like I want to use an iframe, but I can't point it to a different URL, instead I want to use the string that I have and fill the HTML of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like described here: http://bealetech.com/blog/2010/01/25/embedding-html-document-in-an-iframe-with-gwt/

---

*As a reference this is a short summary:*

Create an an [IFrameElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/IFrameElement.html).

```
IFrameElement iframe = Document.get().createIFrameElement();
```

And add it to your page.

Then write the contents of the HTML mail to this element using a native function like this:

```
private final native void fillIframe(IFrameElement iframe, String content) {
    var doc = iframe.document;

    if(iframe.contentDocument)
        doc = iframe.contentDocument; // For NS6
    else if(iframe.contentWindow)
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; // For IE5.5 and IE6

     // Put the content in the iframe
    doc.open();
    doc.writeln(content);
    doc.close();
};
```